# How do I calculate components of an angular rate on end effector frame?

Tags: kinematics, forward-kinematics, rotation

I’ve helped develop the forward kinematic chain for a two-axis gimbal. The Denavit-Hartenberg parameter table for the kinematic chain is given below.

| $\theta$ | $\alpha$ | $r$ | $d$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $90^{\circ}$ | $90^{\circ}$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $180^{\circ} + θ_{1}$ | $90^{\circ}$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $180^{\circ} + θ_{2}$ | $180^{\circ}$ | $0$ | $0$ |

If a known angular rate was applied to a particular joint in the kinematic chain, is there a way of determining the components of that angular rate which would be observed on the end effector frame? For example, if $\theta_{1}$ is rotated at $10$ deg/sec and $\theta_{2}$ equals $270^{\circ}$, what would be the rates observed on the x, y and z axes of the end effector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate that with the Angular Jacobian ($J_\omega$) of the gimbal (see details [here](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/informatik/KI/edu/robotik/ws2017/vel.kin.pdf)).

Based on your D-H, your angular Jacobian should look like:

$$ {\
  J_\omega=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\theta_1) & \sin(\theta_1) \\
    \cos(\theta_1) & -\cos(\theta_1) \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\
}$$

So to obtain the angular speeds of the end efector ${\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z}$ as seen from a grounded frame, you multiply $J_\omega$ by the vector of joint angular speeds $[\dot{\theta}_1, \dot{\theta}_2]^{T}$.

I ran quick calculations, so you need to verify if the Jacobian is correct. But I hope you got the idea.